# How to repair procedural texture for animation?

Tags: animation, texturing, procedural

I made an eye and for texturing I used a procedural approach. It looks fine when the character is in rest position, however when in pose position the whole eye turns red (the materials don't work well anymore?). The file can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oy4utqa1l0grppk/blendstackexhange.blend?dl=0

 I have 2 materials: one for the sclera and one for the iris. The shape of the eye is the following(the selected part is the iris):

[image]

Material preview in edit mode:
[image]

Is there a fix for this? Here is a picture of the eyes in rest and pose position:
[image]

EDIT:
Here is my node setup:
The iris:
[image]

And the sclera:
[image]

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Comment: This is because you are using a texture coordinate system that does not follow the mesh. Try using UV texture coordinates: procedural textures can use them.

Comment: It would help if you posted a screenshot of the material setup for the eyes

Comment: I edited the question with more info and the blend file (I couldn't upload it directly here). If you could take a look again please. How can I use UV for procedural textures ?

Comment: You have to _UV Unwrap_ your object and in the _Shader Editor_ use the _UV_ socket of the _Texture Coordinate_ node instead of _Object_. If you have never used UV maps there is quite a lot to say about it, too much for a short comment here. But there are loads of tutorials on UV unwrapping.

Comment: I've used UV coordinates before, but not for procedural textures. I tried changing to UV socket, however the result is not good.. there must be other changes made in order to work :/

Comment: @Chris sorry for tagging again

Comment: @Gorgious sorry for tagging again

Answer (score -1):

if you uncheck this (bind to vertex groups), it works. Although i am not sure whether you need this... ;)

[image]